# Google Trends Explore - how to get more results than Top Ten

Tags: google-trends

I have just discovered Google Trends.

So far I am trying out the "Explore" feature. It is a very cool tool that shows you the most searched terms + terms "on the rise".

One thing is bugging me, though. How do I get more than the top ten results? For example, the top 100 searched terms instead?